# Get the time that all employees booked at the same time in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list, every item contains a list of booked times for an employee.
ex: if there are 4 employees, it will 4 items in the list of bookings below.

```
bookings = [[
            (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 10, 0)),
            (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 14, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 16, 0)),
            (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 18, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 20, 0))],
            [(datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 15, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 16, 30)),
            (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 19, 0), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 20, 30))
            ],
            [(datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 15, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 17, 0)),
             (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 19, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 21, 0))
            ],
            [(datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 8, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 9, 0)),
             (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 14, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 16, 0)),
            (datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 18, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 20, 0))
            ]]
```

As above, I would like to get the time that all employees booked at the same time.

My output above, the same booked time:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 15, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 16, 0)),
(datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 19, 30), datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, 20, 0))]
```

Please help to give the solution to resolve the above in Python.
Thank you very much!